# to implement SLAM using only kinect and ultrasonic?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, laser, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hai is it possible to develop system implementing SLAM using only kinect and ultrasonic or sonar sensor? coz laser scanner are costly for my project?
also suggest me is there any low cost sensor to go with kinect for SLAM?

my robot has rectangular base. it is like robotic wheel chair using kinect and ultrasonic. im new to ros can any one tell me where to start for this project
and give some link for already done package in above idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54648/to-implement-slam-using-only-kinect-and-ultrasonic?/) by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible. Depending on the environment you might also achieve acceptable results.
You can use pointcloud_to_laserscan to generate lasers from kinect an then run gmapping or hector_mapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on 2013-02-07**:
Depending on the environment ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-08**:
The more features like corners you have, the better. Long hallways or large rooms might be bad, especially considering the limited FOV and max range of a kinect.